# Problems compiling Mingw-Cross-Compiler: "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Tags: windows, macos, makefile, mingw, cross-compiling

I am working on Mac OSX Lion with GCC4.7.0 and my goal is to compile a win32 cross-compiler.

GMP and MPFR, where installed using Macports (GCC47 as well).

Files used:

- w32api-3.17-2-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma
- mingwrt-3.20-mingw32-dev.tar.gz
- binutils-2.22-1-mingw32-src.tar.lzma
- src-gcc-4.7.0-release.tar.7z

Win32 api and mingw runtime libaries, where installed here: **/opt/mingw**

Compiling binutils like this seemed to work fine:

```
 mkdir build
 cd build
 ../configure --prefix=/opt/mingw/ --target=i686-mingw32 --host=x86_64-apple-darwin \
   --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --with-libs=/opt/mingw/lib --with-headers=/opt/mingw/include \
   --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/mingw/include/c++
 make
 sudo make install
```

So the next step, was to compile gcc, but that results in an error, the commands I used:

```
 mkdir build
 cd build
 ../configure --prefix=/opt/mingw/                                              \
          --with-gmp=/opt/local/ --with-mpfr=/opt/local/                        \
          --target=i686-mingw32 --host=x86_64-apple-darwin                      \
          --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --with-libs=/opt/mingw/lib                \
          --with-headers=/opt/mingw/include                                     \
          --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/mingw/include/c++                         \
          --with-gcc --with-tune=generic --disable-werror                       \
          --disable-win32-registry --enable-sjlj-exceptions                     \
          --enable-libstdcxx-debug                                              \
          --enable-cxx-flags='-fno-function-sections -fno-data-sections'        \
          --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs                                \
          --disable-bootstrap --enable-threads --disable-nls                    \
          --enable-languages=c,c++
 make
 sudo make install
```

The command line error:

```
//...
option to accept ISO C89... unsupported
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/Users/Nik/Development/mingw-src/gcc-4.7.0/build/i686-mingw32/libgcc':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The config.log can be found **[here](http://pastebin.com/5Dg0YeD2)**!

It's my first time compiling a cross-compiler and it's a quite complex task, so I hope someone can help me out.

EDIT:

There seems to be some usual c header files missing, but I am unsure how to solve this.

Comment: I am having this same issue, Google isn't giving any answers. See [this topic](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=27279).